# How to move to the next pointer in a smart pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers, smart-pointers

I've been trying to figure out how Smart Pointer arrays work with a test program meant to read in a file one char at a time, and store each char at a pointer in said array. However, I have been having trouble increasing the pointer in order to set later variables of the array. While without smart pointers, I could simply type out, for example,

```
char *check = new char[length];
for (int i =0; i < length; i++);{
    *check=='a';
    check++;
}
```

and it would allow me to assign a value to each pointer in the pointer array, doing the same with a smart pointer array results in the following error upon the line of the 'check++',

```
//This is the smart pointer I've been using, for reference;
std::shared_ptr<char> right(new char(length));
```

```
error: no 'operator++(int)' declared for postfix '++' [-fpermissive]
```

For a moment, let's forget that bracket notation doesn't exist (it works, but I want to know a way to do this in pointer notation), so I can increase or access future pointers in a reliable manner such that I can use it in things like loops to input values in each pointer of a smart pointer array.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the purpose for which `std::shared_ptr` was designed. If you want to iterate through an allocated buffer of, say, `char` values, you should be using `std::vector<char>(length)`, instead.

Comment: `char *check = new char[length];` There is no _pointer array_. There is just a (dynamically-allocated) _character array_. You should maybe better write `check[i]='a';` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr<char>` is a pointer to **one** char. When the shared pointer is destroyed it will call `delete` on it's pointer, and not `delete []`.

You could use a `std::shared_ptr<char[]>`, then you could let that pointer hold an array of chars.

This is however the wrong tool for the job (unless you're working with legacy code or wrapping something that uses raw pointers to arrays). What you want to use is `std::vector<char>` which is a dynamic array to chars with all the memory management abstracted away.

This is how you would use it in a loop, not really sure why you don't want to use the bracket notation as that is the tool for the job here.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> ptr(new char[10]);

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        ptr[i]='a'+i;

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        std::cout << ptr[i] << ' ';
}
```

The better option IMO is to instead use `std::vector<char> ptr(10);`

Comment: This gives me a new perspective on the problem, especially with my error on using brackets, but is there any way for the assigning a variable to a specific pointer in the array and the output of ptr to be in pointer notation?

Comment: @TobiasFizzlewig You can use `char* raw_ptr = ptr.get();` to get a raw pointer from the smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

[`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) does not support arithmetic operation. The purpose of `shared_ptr` is managing the lifetime of the pointer it owns.

When you point to an array and use `[]` operator you index into the array.

Comment: Is there no way to get input into the shared_ptr array using pointer notation?

Comment: @TobiasFizzlewig std::shared_ptr::get() will give you access to the pointer it stores: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get. But you have to be careful to not to generate dangling pointers.

Comment: @TobiasFizzlewig and this std::shared_ptr<char> right(new char(length)); is not doing what you intent. one element with the value length stored in it.